# Is it correct to say "I am a student at the Faculty of X in the university Y"?

Tags: prepositions

Am I saying this right?

> I am a student **at** the Faculty of X **in** the university Y.

For example,

> I am a student **at** the Faculty of Arts **in** the university of Oxford

I know that, for example, one says: "I am a student **at** the university X". I am not sure what happens when there is "the faculty of X" in the play. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Generally, students are not faculty and faculty are not students. Please explain what you are trying to say with more details.

Comment: @Max I am not sure what causes confusion. I am asking about the proper way to say, for example, that: "I am a student at the Faculty of Arts in the university of Oxford". My question is whether or not my usages of "at" and "in" are correct.

Comment: It's confusing because I've never heard of "at the Faculty of X in the university Y". Also, you need to provide specific examples, just like that one because what's right or wrong can depend on a variety of factors, like the school's name.

Comment: I am a student **in** Arts faculty **at** Oxford university (the shorter the sentence, the better, IMO). *In the faculty of X at the university of Y*.

Comment: @Cardinal Thanks. I thought so too. But there are too many variables that I do not understand, like, campus culture, school/college names within the university, the full name of the university,  and differences between US and UK naming. Unless, OP means _I am an art student at Oxford_, then, that's probably universally accepted.

Comment: I'm not following this either. Simply restating the question does not resolve the issue that "faculty" is a workforce, and I don't understand how you could be a student of that. I also wouldn't use "student at" unless is followed by a place. You could be a student of a school, of a subject, or of a teacher, or you could be a student at Harvard, but being a "student at the faculty" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SegNerd Probably too late, but just saw this discussion and thought a clarification may be helpful for future readers:

This is a British VS American English thing. "Faculty" in Britain refers to an academic division. Generally, a university is divided into faculties and each faculty is divided into departments. In the US, "faculty" means a university 'professor' (not necessarily a professor, but a lecturer, professor, teacher, etc.).

So OP is actually asking a valid a question. That being said, I strongly advise against using "faculty" as a division in communications with Americans.

Answer (score 3):

"Faculty" is a venerable term for a university division<sup>1</sup>, still used by some schools either in place of or alongside more modern designations like "department" and "school"<sup>2</sup>.

In all cases (Faculty of X, X Department, etc.) you could say either

> I'm a student ***in*** [Your Division] ***at*** [Your School].

or, if your division has its own "name", such as a named College or professional school within a larger university,

> I'm a student ***at*** [Your Named Division] *at* [Your School].

You could also say

> I'm ***a(n) [your subject]*** student at [Your School].

Your specific example doesn't work, because as far as I can tell, the University of Oxford (the famous old one in England) doesn't currently have a Faculty of Arts.<sup>3</sup> However, one could say:

> I'm a student ***in* the Faculty of Music** at the University of Oxford.
>
> I'm a student ***in* the History of Art Department** at the University of Oxford.
>
> I'm a student ***at* the Ruskin School of Art** at the University of Oxford.

or, respectively,

> I'm an art history/art/music student at Oxford.

The first set are quite formal, suitable for writing in a cover letter to a resume; the last is probably more natural when speaking, and I think would be most universally understood.

**Note that you should avoid saying "I'm an Arts Faculty student", at least in the US, because "faculty" can mean "professor" so it sounds contradictory.**

---

<sup>1</sup> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faculty_of_Arts),

> A **Faculty of Arts** is a university division specializing in teaching in
>   areas traditionally classified as "arts" for academic purposes,
>   generally including creative arts, writing, philosophy, and
>   humanities. It was one of the four traditional divisions of the
>   teaching bodies of medieval universities, the others being Law,
>   Medicine and Theology.

<sup>2</sup> [(Source)](http://umanitoba.ca/faculties/)
[image: U of Manitoba Faculties]

[(Source)](http://C:%5CUsers%5CMeghan%5CDesktop%5C2016-08-18_U_of_Auckland.png)
[image: ![U of Auckland Faculties]

<sup>3</sup> [(Source)](http://www.ox.ac.uk/about/divisions-and-departments)
[image: U of Oxford]

Answer (score 0):

I think better you say that : I am X Faculty student at university Y

For example, I am Commerce student at Cambridge University.

Comment: Note that, for example, York University is in Canada, whereas the University of York is in England, because "of" is part of the university's name.

Comment: then "I am a student at the Faculty of Arts in the university of Oxford" can be used.